# Как прописать в коде, что заданное число не должно быть кратно 100

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прописать в коде следующее:
Заданное число должно быть кратно 4, но не кратно 100.

Comment: `if число % 100 == 0: print('Ошибка, число оказалось кратно 100')`

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор "%" показывает остаток при делении числа. Если остаток равен 0, то число кратно, если не равен нулю, то не кратно.

```py
if number % 4 == 0 and number % 100 != 0:
    print('Число кратно 4 и не кратно 100.')
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!